# Please explain this compare method

Tags: java, compareto

```
public int compareTo(Name other) {
    int result = this.familyName.compareTo(other.familyName);

    if (result == 0) {
        result = this.firstName.compareTo(other.firstName);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I can't comprehend the meat of the code, how it is used to compare names.

Comment: It's delegating to the string's `compareTo` method.

Comment: Which part is unclear?

Comment: Delegating to the string class, in the context of business logic, if family names are same then comparing by firstnames.

Answer (score 0):

If the family names are the same, then it compares the first name.

Essentially "grouping by" family name.

Answer (score 0):

This is the `compareTo` method of a class implementing the `Comparable` (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. The return value of `compareTo` is defined to be `0` if the objects are identical, `< 0` if the argument is lexicographically greater, and `> 0` if the argument is less.

The result of the comparison of the `Name` object you have here is delegated to the `compareTo` method of the `familyName` attribute. That means the `familyName` attribute of the current `Name` object is compared to the argument's `familyName` attribute. The second `compareTo` check is only done if the `familyName` attributes of both `Name` object instances are identical. If that's the case, the `firstName` is compared instead.